# how to record value via html form into mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have made a bootstrap contact form but i don't really know how to insert the submitted values into my local database(mysql). Here's my html form:

```
<!--Contact Section-->
<div id="contact" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
  <h2 class="text-center">CONTACT</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <p>Contact us and we'll get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Lagos, Nigeria</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span><a href="tel:+2347068613892"> +234 7068613892 </a></p>


    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span><a href="mailto:sparkidea@gmail.com"> Sparkidea@gmail.com </a></p>
    </div>
    <form role="form" id="contactForm" class="contact-form" data-toggle="validator" class="shake">
    <div class="col-sm-7 slideanim" method="post" action="php/mail-core.php">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required required data-error="Please enter your name">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required required data-error="Please enter your email">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="msg_subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required data-error="Please enter your message subject">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" type="tel" required required data-error="Please enter your Phone Number">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="5" required data-error="Write your message"></textarea><br>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
            <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"  style="padding-bottom: 20px;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need help with recording the data inserted into the form above, thanks!

Comment: You can start by reader [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with. If you dont know how to insert data at all using php to mysql you need to start with a simple tutorial and learn that first.

Comment: I don't know how to insert data at all

Answer (score 0):

I will use a little form as example but it also works with your form of course.

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
    <input name="login" type="text" />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Above there is a form that send its content using the HTTP POST method. It means that you'll be able to get the fields content using the `$_POST` array in PHP.

post.php

```
<?php
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
?>
```

Above there is the post.php file content. When you submit your form, fields content is sent to this file. As you can see, the content of the `name` attribute is the key in the `$_POST` array. The input with name = 'login' can be retrieved in $_POST['login']